# match special types in C

Tags: syntax-highlighting

`vim` has some great highlighting for built-in keywords, functions and types, but when working on some non-built-in projects, this seems not enough.

For instance, the keyword before a variable is mostly a `type` keyword. Take a `gtk` program for example:

In `vim`:

[image: first]

Where the three `GtkWidget`s should be marked as `type` as that in SO:

[image: SO]

These are some basic syntax for the C language. Can one in `vim` do the same highlighting?

Comment: I don't think this is possible for Vim in the general case. To distinguish `a b(c);`  as a function declaration or a variable declaration, you have to know whether `c` is a type. For just `a b`, it might be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several plugins in [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=gtk&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search) that should accomplish that, for instance:

- [gtk-vim-syntax : Syntax highlighting for GLib, Gtk+, Xlib, Gimp, Gstreamer, and more.](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1000)
- [GTK+ : GTK+-2.2 syntax highlight](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=570)

If no existing plugin work as you expect them you should consider writing a new one (and possibly including it in vim.org) by following the explanation in [`:help usr_44`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_44.txt.html#usr_44.txt) -- "Your own syntax highlighted".

Comment: Hmm, the syntax highlighting are good, though I think vim *can* do as that like compilers to distinguish types, vars, and functions (which is my original thought) , it will definitely be complicated.